# Where does sitecore store item statistics data in database..?

Tags: sql, lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

i just want to know where sitecore stores Items statistics data. Using SQL query i want to get recently updated items.
i write a query for Sitecore_Master database on Items table, there i found created,updated fields as well, while these columns contains different values with sitecore item statistic values
my sql query is:

```
 select name,created,updated from items where id='{EFDC1A0B-C40D-42B9-880B-0A09D4686E60}'
```

it is working for me, while i need statistics data.

Anyone have idea which table sitecore used to store statistics data for sitecore item.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore stores `Created` and `Updated` values for every specific version of the item. That's why it's stored in the `VersionedFields` table.

You can use this query to get items updated after `2015-10-27`:

```sql
SELECT
    vf.Value AS Updated,
    item.ID AS ItemId,
    item.Name AS ItemName
FROM
    VersionedFields vf 
    JOIN Items item ON item.ID = vf.ItemId
WHERE
    vf.FieldId = 'D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522' -- id of the __updated field
    -- vf.FieldId = '25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497' -- id of the __created field
    AND vf.Value > '20151027'
```

Please keep in mind that Sitecore stores dates in UTC in the table.

Comment: Thanks @Marek , it is working for me, exactly i was looking for this,Thanks again.